# how to Set Radio button value checked from mock json

Tags: json, angular, angular2-forms

In Angularjs2, I am new to angularjs2. I need to fix checkbox is in defaultly 
   checked when I get the values from mock json file. Anyone Plzz?

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="formHeading">Skills *</div>
    <input #one name="skills" type="checkbox" [value]="one" ngControl="skills" (click)="skills=one.value" [(ngModel)]="profile.skills" />
        One
     <input #two name="skills" type="checkbox" [value]="two" ngControl="skills" (click)="skills=two.value" [(ngModel)]="profile.skills" />
        Two
        <control-messages control="skills"></control-messages>  
 </div>
```

I already fixed my values in json file.

```
[{

"skills": "one",

}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try : [checked]="skills == 'one'"

Comment: Hi Parwej, Thanx for ur response. But its not work out. :(

Comment: @lved I think is different than this. Can you check in console log? is there any issue? or you can put your sample on punker etc..